# C# Replace regex matched pattern using dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to replace a pattern in my string where only the words between the tags should be replaced. The word that needs to be replaced resides in a dictionary as key and value pair.

Currently this is what I am trying:

```
string input = "<a>hello</a> <b>hello world</b> <c>I like apple</c>";
string pattern = (@"(?<=>)(.)?[^<>]*(?=</)");
Regex match = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = match.Matches(input);

var dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
dictionary1.Add("hello", "Hi");
dictionary1.Add("world", "people");
dictionary1.Add("apple", "fruit");

string output = "";

output = match.Replace(input, replace => { return dictionary1.ContainsKey(replace.Value) ? dictionary1[replace.Value] : replace.Value; });
Console.WriteLine(output);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Using this, it does replace but only the first 'hello' and not the second one. I want to replace every occurrence of 'hello' between the tags.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think your regex is matching the values between the tags, so the matches you're trying to replace are `hello`, `hello world` and `I like apple`. Are you trying to match on individual words? So your output should be `<a>hi</a> <b>hi people</b> <c>I like fruit</c>`?

Comment: Using regex on XML is generally considered a Bad Idea.

Comment: yes this is exactly how I want the output to be. Is my regex the problem here?

Comment: Yes, your regex isn't quite right, but I can't seem to come up with something that does what you want! My regex skills are somewhat rusty...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the matches are:

- hello
- hello world
- I like apple

so e.g. `hello world` is not in your dictionary.

Based on your code, this could be a solution:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        dictionary1.Add("hello", "Hi");
        dictionary1.Add("world", "people");
        dictionary1.Add("apple", "fruit");


        string input = "<a>hello</a> <b>hello world</b> <c>I like apple</c>";
        string pattern = ("(?<=>)(.)?[^<>]list|" + GetKeyList(dictionary1) + "(?=</)");
        Regex match = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matches = match.Matches(input);

        string output = "";

        output = match.Replace(input, replace => {
            Console.WriteLine(" - " + replace.Value);

            return dictionary1.ContainsKey(replace.Value) ? dictionary1[replace.Value] : replace.Value;
        });
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }

    private static string GetKeyList(Dictionary<string, string> list)
    {
         return string.Join("|", new List<string>(list.Keys).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zNkEDv

If someone wants to dig into this an tell me why do I need a "list|" in the list (because the first item is being ignored), I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Here's a fiddle where I print these out: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kTP1i3

Comment: This certainly tells the OP what the problem is... Are you planning on providing a solution?

Comment: Will do @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: this works well! however, I don't clearly understand what you have done in to match the pattern?

Comment: @d.him basically I'm building a word list based on the dictionary. So the final expression would be `"(?<=>)(.)?[^<>]list|hello|world|apple(?=</)"` and itdl match those words inside the elements

Comment: and GetKeyList is where you are extracting all the keys from the dictionary and joining them?

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of doing it - I parse the string into XML and then select elements containing the keys in your dictionary and then replace each element's value.
However, you have to have a valid XML document - your example lacks a root node.

```
    var xDocument = XDocument.Parse("<root><a>hello</a> <b>hello world</b> <c>I like apple</c></root>");
    var dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { { "hello", "Hi" }, { "world", "people" }, { "apple", "fruit" } };

    string pattern = @"\w+";
    Regex match = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    var xElements = xDocument.Root.Descendants()
                      .Where(x => dictionary1.Keys.Any(s => x.Value.Contains(s)));

    foreach (var xElement in xElements)
    {
        var updated = match.Replace(xElement.Value, 
                           replace => {
                                return dictionary1.ContainsKey(replace.Value) 
                                   ? dictionary1[replace.Value] : replace.Value; });
        xElement.Value = updated;
    }
    string output = xDocument.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

This pattern of `"\w+"` matches words, not spaces.
This LINQ selects descendants of the root node where the element value contains any of the keys of your dictionary:

```
var xElements = xDocument.Root.Descendants().Where(x => dictionary1.Keys.Any(s => x.Value.Contains(s)));
```

I then iterate through the `XElement` enumerable collection returned and apply your replacement MatchEvaluator to just the string value, which is a lot easier!

The final output is `<root><a>Hi</a><b>Hi people</b><c>I like fruit</c></root>`. You could then remove the opening and closing `<root>` and `</root>` tags, but I don't know what your complete XML looks like.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want (*from what you have provided so far*):

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> dict;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  dict =
    new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
      {
        { "hello", "Hi" },
        { "world", "people" },
        { "apple", "fruit" }
      };

  var input = "<a>hello</a> <b>hello world</b> apple <c>I like apple</c> hello";
  var pattern = @"<.>([^<>]+)<\/.>";
  var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, Replacer);

  Console.WriteLine(output);
  Console.ReadLine();
}

static string Replacer(Match match)
{
  var value = match.Value;
  foreach (var kvp in dict)
  {
    if (value.Contains(kvp.Key)) value = value.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
  }
  return value;
}
```